# Regex to pull out Suburbs from block of text

Tags: regex, vba, outlook

this may be an impossible task, I can't seem to find a useful answer on good old Google.

What I want to do is pull out the suburbs from a block of text. There is a general format, so I *think* it should be possible.

i.e. "Services in the areas of landsdale (WA) may be disrupted"

It is not always properly capitalised, may contain suburbs with multiple words (such as "South Coogee") or it may contain multiple suburbs. The suburbs always come after "area of" or "areas of" and the suburbs always preceed "(WA)".

I have very limited experience with regex, so I've got no idea where to even start. A solution would be great, but I am happy to be pointed in the right direction if no one here has the time/patience to develop a regex string query for this.

Comment: what environment are you extracting this in?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention this is for VBA

Comment: From your comment below this is Outlook VBA. is your text in the body of a message, do you have multiple messages to parse etc [damn Telstra :)]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To be honest, Regex seems to me like overkill, so I wouldn't even bother, and just use native VBA string manipulation functions.

```
s = "Services in the area of landsdale (WA) may be disrupted"
prefix1 = "area of"
prefix2 = "areas of"
suffix = "(WA)"

' Is it "area" or "areas"?
If InStr(s, prefix1) > 0 Then
    prefix = prefix1
Else
    prefix = prefix2
End If

suburb = Trim(Mid(s, InStr(s, prefix) + Len(prefix) + 1, _
    InStr(s, suffix) - InStr(s, prefix) - Len(prefix) - 1))
```

Also, "the **areas** of landsdale (WA)" doesn't really make syntactical sense (why the plural?), which makes me suspect that you sometimes have phrases of the form: "the areas of landsdale (WA) and crumpetville (WA)" or "the areas of landsdale, crumpetville and metawan (WA)". But this is just speculation on my part.

Comment: Hi Jean-Francois, you are somewhat correct. It is horrible English, but to be honest, it's from Telstra, so I'm not too surprised (it is a real example). The second speculation is correct, suburbs would be comma separated if there are multiple suburbs.

Nice solution by the way, I didn't actually think of doing something like that. This is why I love stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 3):

I'd like to offer you the full-blown regex example for your reference. Personally I don't think it's very scary in this case :) I apologize that I'm not sure how this needs to be modified (if ata ll) for use in Outlook, but this is the function as it would be written in Excel.

```
Function ExtractSuburb(ByVal text As String)

Dim RE As Object, allMatches As Object
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")

RE.pattern = "areas? of (.+) \(WA\)"
RE.Global = True
Set allMatches = RE.Execute(text)

ExtractSuburb = allMatches.Item(0).submatches.Item(0)

End Function
```

Quite literally this pattern is telling the function to grab whatever is between "area/areas of " and " (WA)". I can see how the inner workings of Regex can be confusing, though, so hats off to Jean for offering a different solution.

Comment: Thanks Issun, doesn't seem to be quite right for Outlook unfortunately and as Jean's solution works, it's easier than figuring out how to modify yours for outlook. Thanks for your efforts :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your data you could probably ignore the first and last parts and only deal with "areas of landsdale (WA)". Using that the following regex works:

`areas? of (.+?) \(WA\)`

It matches 'area' or 'areas' of (the suburb) followed by '(WA)'.

I hope this helps and I can extend it to better fit your data if need be.

Answer (score 1):

You are not indicating which regex dialect you want to use, but something like `/areas? of (\w+(\s\w+)*?) \(WA\)/` should work in any reasonably  Perl-flavored implementation. The *? selects as few repeated words as possible between "of" and "(WA)". If your text may have irregular spacing, you'll have to tweak for that.